# Периодический подвисает apache, Request exceeded the limit of 10

Tags: apache, веб-сервер

Есть сайт, который время от времени перестает отвечать на запросы.
Подозреваю что проблема кроется в роутинге т.к. в логах находится куча ошибок:
**Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.**

Я плохо знаю apache, и поэтому прошу подсказать что в этом htaccess не так, я некого не прошу его переписывать, просто дайте совета.
Также есть подозрение что проблема может быть в неоптимизированных запросах к  БД.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files

Deny from 10.10.1.5

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

 # SEO URL Settings
 RewriteEngine On
 # If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure     you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /

#Создание ссылок ЧПУ

###RewriteRule ^$1/$2/$3 /index.php?route=$1/$4&path=$2&product_id=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.html$ index.php?route=information/sitemap [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^catalog\.html /index.php?route=product/category [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^news\.html(.*) /index.php?route=information/news$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^works\.html(.*) /index.php?route=information/works$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^articles\.html(.*) /index.php?route=information/articles$1   [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)\.html /index.php?       route=information/reviews&rreview_id=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^reviews\.html(.*) /index.php?route=information/reviews$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^information/([^?]*) index.php?route=information/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^product/([^?]*) index.php?route=product/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cache_([^?]*) cache.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^news/([^?]*) /index.php?route=information/news/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myserver\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myserver.com/$1 [R=301,L]

##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
##RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule /eksklyuzivnaya-vinnaya-kollekciya/    http://myserver,com/vino/eksklyuzivnaya-vinnaya-kollektsiya/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /Vieil_Armagnac_Sempe_1948_Sempyе_V_ei_Arman_jаk-v_podar_up/   http://myserver,com/krepkie-napitki/armanyak/vieil-armagnac-sempe-1948-sempe-vej-  armanyak-v-podarup/ [R=301,L]
#Redirect 301 /Dopff_au_Moulin_Dopf_o_Mulen/ http://myserver,com/dopff-au-moulindopf-o-mulen/


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://myserver,com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^yandexmarket.xml$ index.php?route=feed/yandex_market [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the   following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200
php_value max_input_vars 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

Т. к. в .htaccess выполняется перенаправление запросов с www на имя сайте без www, то нужно проверить настройки CMS, относящиеся к имени сайту, т. к. там, скорее всего, указано имя с www и CMS пытается выполнить обратное перенаправление.

Comment: Да, там одинаковое имя. Это может вызывать серьезные проблемы?

Comment: @QWERTY, нет, само имя в .htaccess проблем вызывать не будет :) Но если оно отличается от имени сайта, заданного в настройках CMS - то, в зависимости от CMS,это может приводить к проблемам, в том числе и описанными вами. У вас же OpenCart? Вам нужно убедиться, что в файлах config.php и admin/config.php, в параметрах, относящихся к имени сайта ('HTTP_SERVER' и 'HTTPS_SERVER'), указано имя сайта без www, т. е., как и в файле .htaccess.

Comment: К сожалению там все ok(